# Math and Variable Issues- Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a simple calculator, but the IDE I'm using keeps telling me I'm trying to perform math operations with strings. I tried assigning all the variables to doubles, but it hasn't worked.

```
 """Calculator program"""


loop = 1  # 1 means loop; anything else means don't loop.
choice = 0  # This variable holds the user's choice in the menu
add1 = 0.0
add2 = 0.0
sub1 = 0.0
sub2 = 0.0
mul1 = 0.0
mul2 = 0.0
div1 = 0.0
div2 = 0.0
result = 0.0
while loop == 1:
    # Print the options user has
    print ("Welcome to calculator.py")

    print ("your options are:")
    print (" ")
    print ("1) Addition")
    print ("2) Subtraction")

    print ("3) Multiplication")

    print ("4) Division")
    print ("5) Quit calculator.py")
    print (" ")
    #Perform the desired operation
    choice = int(input("Choose your option: ").strip())
    if choice == 1:
        add1 = input()
        add2 = input()
        result = add1 + add2
        print(add1, add2)
        print (add1, "+", add2, "=", result)
    elif choice == 2:
        sub2 = input()
        sub1 = input()
        result = sub1 - sub2
        print (sub1, "-", sub2, "=", result)
    elif choice == 3:
        mul1 = input("Multiply this: ")
        mul2 = input("with this: ")
        result = mul1 * mul2
        print (mul1, "*", mul2, "=", result)
    elif choice == 4:
        div1 = input("Divide this: ")
        div2 = input("by this: ")
        result = div1 / div2
        print (div1, "/", div2, "=", result)
    elif choice == 5:
        loop = 0

print ("Thank-you for using calculator.py!")
```

Comment: @casperOne: It is not difficult to tell what is asked. He is new to Python. Obviously, he does not know what exactly should be asked. But the answers are clear. Please, reopen the question and let the asker the chance to communicate with the world.

Comment: "has not worked" fits the definitions of ambiguous, vague and incomplete.

Comment: @casperone: Thank you for closing the 'vague' question, but I do not see how it is vague. I am new to Python, this is the first program I've even attempted to write. 'Has not worked' noes not fit ambiguous. Ambiguous: "Open to more than one interpretation.' In this case, 'has not worked' states that the solution I tried did not work. You may be wondering how it didn't work, but it's irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @pepr: Thank you for your support. However Chimp and Martijn Pieters answered the question very nicely.

Comment: "but it hasn't worked." isn't too specific.  Those who answered took the time to figure it out, but generally, that onus should *not* be on the people trying to answer, it is on the person *asking*.  Just saying "it doesn't work" is not the sign of a well-defined question.

Comment: @casperOne: Yes, it is vague. But we are not machines. And the Stack Overflow is here to help, not to be the collection of perfectly formulated questions and answers. In my opinion, one should also look at the reputation of the asker and how much is he or she a novice. Once he is more experienced, he will learn that perfectly formulated question is the half of the solution. But he is beginner in Python, and as such, the vague question should be tolerated.

Comment: @pepr That's a discussion for [meta] (if you wish), but fair warning, you'll find that generally, the rules apply across the gamut, for high and low rep users.  They're applied equally; if they weren't, then we'd have a large influx of low-quality questions.  And yes, we are actually here to curate good answers *and* questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, not a number. You'll have to convert that:

```
add1 = int(input())
```

or

```
add1 = float(input())
```

depending on what you want your calculator to support, otherwise you are *indeed* performing maths operations with strings.

Comment: This solution worked, thank you. I wish I'd known this beforehand so I wouldn't have had to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try sticking a

```
    int()
```

on it to make

```
    int(input))
```

Hope this helps